# Подключение страниц на сайте

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Как на сайте сделать так чтобы при переходе по ссылке открывалась новая страница? Т.е. в меню есть пункт 'контакты', при нажатии на этот пункт (при переходе по ссылке `<a href="contacts"...`) должен меняться контент, а хеадер и футер должны быть статичны. Понимаю что разные страницы подключаются в теле через `include`, а вот как понять на какую страницу подключить?

Answer (score 1):

В простейшем случае как у вас (без использования шаблонизаторов) просто структура каждой странички должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?php
require "header.php"

// content

require "footer.php"
```

Comment: А нельзя сделать так чтобы подключался именно контент страницы? И как вообще понять какую страницу подключить? Читать по `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` я так понял не получится

Comment: Если хотите без перезагрузки, тогда Ajax.

Comment: Что значит как понять? Вы сами напишите в ссылке что-то типа <a href="contacts.php">. Загрузится страница contacts.php. Если её код выглядит как я написал в ответе, то футер и хедер будут стандартными.

Comment: Если копировать ссылку и ставить в новом окне, то по этой ссылке будет открываться при ajax?

Comment: Если прописать так `<a href="contacts.php">` по в адресной строке будет `/contacts.php`, а нужно чтобы было просто `/contacts`

Comment: Или это потом отдельно настраивается?

Comment: Это уже настройка ЧПУ. Для разных серверов есть разные решения. Для apache mod_rewrite например.

Comment: Спасибо большое!